# neo4j: is there a way to SKIP over results based on the total length of the result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a query returning all nodes of a certain type. I'm trying to return only 10 results which are evenly distributed over the whole set.

I've tried:

```
$START t=node(*) 
MATCH (image:Image) RETURN image.name ORDER BY image.name 
SKIP toInt(count(image.name)/10);
```

However this returns an error message saying that I'm not allowed to use variables in SKIP.

I thought that I could try and re-run the whole statement in the count function then:

```
START t=node(*) 
MATCH (image:Image) RETURN image.name ORDER BY image.name
SKIP toInt(count(MATCH (image:Image) RETURN image.name)/10);
```

However this returns an invalid input error:

```
Invalid input 'R': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ')' (line 3, column 38 (offset: 112))
"SKIP toInt(count(MATCH (image:Image) RETURN image.name)/10);"
                                      ^
```

Comment: If you are only trying to return 10 result, why not use `LIMIT 10`?

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas limit 10 only returns first 10, all the images are sorted in time order and I want to grab 10 samples from equal distance apart (i.e. if I had 50 images in my set, I'd want to return every 5th image)

Comment: Okay! Next question: which version are you using? Since Neo4j 2.0+, you do not need the `START` clause (you do not use the value of `t` anyways).

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas Sorry, that's my mistake - I was trying to modify some older stackoverflow code

Answer (score 0):

You could [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#aggregation-collect) the results to a list and then return 10 elements from the collection:

```
MATCH (image:Image)
WITH image.name AS imageName
ORDER BY imageName
WITH COLLECT(imageName) AS imageNames, range(0, 10) AS indices
UNWIND indices AS index
RETURN imageNames[toInt(length(imageNames) * index / 10)]
```

To get the indices, we create a list of 10 numbers (0, ..., 9), [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-unwind) them get 10 separate rows and spread them across the indices.

Note that this query will not be very efficient as the server has to compute and collect all results, but the results set will only contain 10 rows.

(Note: I have not tested the query.)